# .NET Core with .NET Framework as TargetFramework

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-framework-version

I'm wondering what it means, exactly, when I have a .NET Core console app project that has its TargetFramework property (in the .csproj) set to a version of the full .NET Framework, e.g.

```
<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
```

- If I compile this as a console application, will it use the .NET Core runtime, or the .NET Framework runtime?
- If it uses the .NET Core runtime, can I encounter any incompatibilities between supported features in .NET Core and .NET Framework if I remain on the Windows platform?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have `<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>`, then you don't have a .NET Core console app. You have a .NET Framework app that simply makes use of the newer csproj tweaks in the project file, and which can be easily built with the `dotnet` command-line tool.

Comment: Yes, I suspected as much. Does this also mean that it will use the standard .NET runtime?

Comment: @Eyvind yes, it is 100% regular .NET Framework; if you want to target .NET Core, you need to use `netcoreapp{version}`; note that *libraries* can declare themselves agnostic by targeting `netstandard{version}`; what they *actually* end up running on depends on what the *executable* targets